# How to add more tables in mlflow?

Tags: mlflow

I want to add more tables in mlflow.

As mlflow provide facility to do machine learning experiments but I just want to add those experiment in project level that User can create multiple projects and in that project multiple experiment can be performed.

So, Is their any way to achieve this feature in mlflow

Comment: Do you want to create new experiments to log your runs under those?

Comment: When I was started working with mlflow, so I don't know where the data were actually stores. After some R&D I found that initially mlflow doesn't store data in tables, means they  are managing records or experiments in file system. And they also provide an facility to store that experiments and other details in table as well. And I found the file where I need to add the code to add more tables. They are using SQL-Alchemy structure, So in that db modules file we can add the SQL-Alchemy code to add the more tables.

Answer (score 1):

As per there documentation they are using SqlAlchemy ORM for the database connectivity, if you want to add any more tables then you just need to create new model class in the respective files.